# AFURLConnectionOperation.m Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking

I got a warning in `Xcode 5.1` as stated below

```
AFNetworking 2.2.0: AFURLConnectionOperation.m Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')
```

Is this important?

Comment: make the conversion explicit and the warning will go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mean is arm64 architecture `int64_t` range is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807` but `int` range is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. so compiler say to Loss of value.

See a this: [ConvertingYourAppto-64Bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html)

if you don't want more warning. you can must change to architecture in Xcode 5.1 [image: enter image description here]![enter image description here][image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I see the problem. I wait for the AFNetworking update.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the following change manually until the next CocoaPod release (the change is already in [GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/e94a52cdf167798f980216ae2d9a3ae29ac56254#diff-53e6fe9795cc68ba4174ef84195348bf)).

change:

```
[decoder decodeInt64ForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(totalBytesRead))];
```

to:

```
[decoder decodeIntegerForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(totalBytesRead))];
```

Answer (score 2):

AFNetworking v2.2.1 fixes this issue.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/CHANGES

Answer (score 0):

you probably select as simulator : iPhone Retina (4-inch **64-bit**). Try with the 32 bits

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no warning in 32 bit.