# After updated to Xcode 5.1 got more than 130 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just updated to Xcode 5.1, however my error free project is become really bad. Got 130 error at the moment nearly all of them is some king of "Value Conversion Issue" or "Format String issue". I think the new processor the A7 is causing the error because the Xcode 5.1 is added the armv7s architecture to my project. I would like to remove it. My program runned fine on 5S without supporting the armv7s architecture I don't need it now too and i won't rewrite about 4500 lines just for this. So i would like to now how can i UNSUPPORT the armv7s architecture or solve this issue.

Please help me.

Comment: Try compiling for 32Bits instead of 64-bit. cf [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350056/afurlconnectionoperation-m-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-int64-t/22350154?noredirect=1#comment33975738_22350154)

Comment: You should actually fix the bad code. There is a good reason you are getting all of these new errors. Post a couple of examples so people can show you what to fix.

Comment: Its about 140 error . This all because the new 64 bit came. I have error event in a formatted string like: [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%i",10]; Because, I don't know why, but the 64 bit doesn't support the type 'int'. It always request NSUinteger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your project Build Settings, select Valid Architectures, and remove arm64.

Comment: When I remove arm64 architecture, my project does not build anymore !